# Interpolation with default if key not exists

Tags: javascript, string, interpolation, string-interpolation

I found a short snippet for string-interpolation on [GitHub](https://github.com/toddmotto/interpolate/blob/master/src/interpolate.js) and shortened it to this:

```
var interpolate = function (tmpl, data) {
    return new Function('data', 'with(data){return \'' + 
        tmpl.replace(/{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}/g, '\'+($1)+\'') + '\';}')(data);
};
```

It works fine for this:

```
interpolate('Hello {{user.name}}!', {user: {name: 'Admin'}});
// Hello Admin!
```

But there are two results I don´t like:

```
interpolate('Hello {{user.firstname}}!', {user: {name: 'Admin'}});
// Hello undefined!
```

and this one:

```
interpolate('Hello {{user.name}}!', {userinfo: {name: 'Admin'}});
// Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined(…)
```

Is there a way to modify the snipped to use a default (empty string) if the key does not exist?

**UPDATE**
Now I found a solution for all my requirements:

```
function interpolate(tmpl, data, defaultValue, reg) {       
    return tmpl.replace(reg || /{{([^{}]*)}}/g, function(a, b) {
        try {
            return new Function('data', ['with(data){return ',b,' || \'',(defaultValue || ''),'\';}'].join(''))(data);
        }
        catch(e) {
            return defaultValue || '';                  
        }
    });
}

interpolate('Existing value: {{user.name}} - global value: {{Date.now()}} - undefined: {{user.age}} - exception: {{dat.haha}}', {user: {name: 'Admin'}}, '?');
// "Existing value: Admin - global value: 1441555682168 - undefined: ? - exception: ?"
```

Suggestions are wellcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, assuming you have only one placeholder in the string:

```js
var interpolate = function(s, data) {
  var RE= /{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}/,
      sp= s.match(RE)[1].split('.');  //example: ['user','name']

  sp.forEach(function(key) {
    data= data[key] || '';   //walk the object, defaulting to null string if undefined
  });
  
  return s.replace(RE, data);
};

console.log(interpolate('Hello {{user.name}}!', {user: {name: 'Admin'}}));

console.log(interpolate('Hello {{user.firstname}}!', {user: {name: 'Admin'}}));

console.log(interpolate('Hello {{user.name}}!', {userinfo: {name: 'Admin'}}));
```

> Unfortunately expressions like {{Date.now()}} dont´t work with this
>   solution

In that case, you *do* need to use `new Function()` or `eval()`.

You can add short-circuit evaluation (`|| ''`) to the function declaration string to avoid undefined object properties, along with `try...catch` to avoid uncaught reference errors.

In the following Snippet, the function string for the second example ends up looking something like this:

```
with(data) try {
  return 'Hello '+(user.firstname || "")+'!';
} catch(e) {
  return 'Hello !'
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var interpolate = function (tmpl, data) {
  var f= 'with(data) try{return \'' + 
           tmpl.replace(/{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}/g, ('\'+($1 || "")+\'') ) + '\';}'+
         'catch(e) {return \'' +
           tmpl.replace(/{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}/g, '') + "'"+
         '}';
  return new Function('data', f)(data);
};

console.log(interpolate('Hello {{user.name}}, it is currently {{Date()}}!', {user: {name: 'Admin'}}));

console.log(interpolate('Hello {{user.firstname}}!', {user: {name: 'Admin'}}));

console.log(interpolate('Hello {{user.name}}!', {userinfo: {name: 'Admin'}}));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a correct anwer to my question. Unfortunately expressions like {{Date.now()}} dont´t work with this solution, but this wasn´t part of my question, so I accepted your answer.

Comment: Ha, as soon as I updated my answer, I see that you found your own answer to the problem.  Good job.